# How to specify view controller for Ext js 6 window

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

In extjs, how to create view controller for a window, and how to make a window a child of a panel similar like this:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Main', {
    items: [
        { xtype: 'textfield' },
        { xtype: 'window' }
    ]
});
```

The reason is I want to enable the same view controller to handle both panel and window actions. But Panel doesn't seem to accept window as its child.

A work around for this is to have in controller init:

```
//...
init: function(view) {
    this.myWindow = new Ext.window.Window();
}
```

But doing it this way will have the window's view controller pointed to global app controller, which is unwanted. So to work around this, I can add a bunch of listeners to the window, but this is not preferred.

Is there anyway I can achieve this without those ugly workarounds?

Comment: You could try whether you can bind one ViewController to two different views - your main view and the window. Apart from that workaround, which I am not sure will work, no, there isn't. A window is a floating component, so it is by definition kept outside the usual component hierarchy. The other possibility would be to use a [Controller](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.app.Controller.html), which is global for your application.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a view controller for a window I will suggest something here. You can create window and attach the all component which associate to the window. Sample code for this will something look like.

```
Ext.define("App.view.NewWin.NewWint", {
    extend: "Ext.window.Window",
    alias: 'widget.newWindow',
    layout: 'fit',
    scrollable: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    modal: true,
    requires: [
      'App.view.NewWin.NewWintController'
    ],
    controller: 'newWindowController',
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this, 
        // Code for attributes if in case any required  
        me.tbar = [
          // Code for TBar
        ];
        me.items = [{
          // Code for WindowItem 
        }];
        me.buttons = ['->', { // some code for tbar
            text: Save,
            name: "Save",
            hidden: me.readOnly,
            disabled: true
        }, {
            text: Cancle,
            name: "cancel"
        }];
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
})
```

Since we assigned a controller `newWindowController` in window definition then we can use a controller separately. Sample code  will follow this

```
Ext.define('App.view.NewWin.NewWintController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.newWindowController',

    init: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.control({
        // You can write the control for your component which is in window.
        });
    },


    /*
     * The code below will work on click of save.
     */
    onSaveBtns: function(btn) {
        var me = this,
        // You code for save 
    },
    onClose: function(btn) {
        var window = btn.up("window");
        window.close();
    }
});
```

Now the second part is how to make a window a child of a panel, afte  a bit research i found this > [Panel as item](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?144013-How-to-add-Ext-window-in-side-an-Ext-panel) you can try this concept. I created a fiddle where you can play around [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1kv6).

**Note** In your case instead of creating window inside panel you can directly use `xtype : 'newWindow'`

Comment: I tried to run your fiddle, the window wasn't rendered inside the panel. It's the problem I;ve been dealing with, window is ignored so I can't attach listeners for window directly to window owner container.

Comment: Ya, In fiddle is window is aside to panel. I asked to check with code. any way why you want to attach window inside a panel. can you give some detail about your requirement. Hard to understand window as a part of panel. can you please give a light on this

Comment: It's the extjs thing with the way you bind event handler to controller. Say there have a panel, which some time later will popup a window, containing a form. Ideally all the interaction logic of that popup window should belongs to the panel. Having a window as a child of the panel will ensure the encapsulation.

Comment: Great hold one a sec here. You said "pop a window". Popup a window need to fire some event. As in my answer I suggest write a separate code for window and also explain how to write controller, so you can use this window when you firing an event. Feel free to correct me if I wrong

Comment: There nothing wrong with your approach and in fact, its been my fallback all the time. I just wanted to know if I could use window as if it was a normal component inside a panel, so i can encapsula te all handlers of that window to panel viewcontroller without any extra work. Sorry for the original question, writing a controller for window is not really what I wanted to ask. By encapsulate i mean i can put panel viewctronller method name as a string to any of event inside that window

Answer (score 0):

Binding one controller to different views is kind of against the idea of MVC..
But you could try just to assign one, many times.
You can give controller to the window in the definition, like:
http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/classic/window/window.html

Answer (score 0):

> But Panel doesn't seem to accept window as its child.

Window is a floating panel, having a window as a child of a panel makes no sense, why don't you use a panel or a container directly instead? You can open windows programatically if you want. See docs for [window](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.window.Window.html).

I would recommend you to have a ViewController per View. If you have common methods for several controllers you can have a superclass with those methods and then extend the other controllers from that one:

```
Ext.define('My.SuperController', {
    init : function() {
        this.getView().on('event', this.myHandler);
    }
});
Ext.define('My.PanelController', {
     extend : 'My.SuperController'
});
Ext.define('My.WindowController', {
     extend : 'My.SuperController'
});
```